# One function for multiple outcomes

Tags: javascript, html

I have wrote this simple function to open a new window onclick;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function solopopup()
{
mywindow = window.open("http://www.sample.com/solopopup","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=768,height=850");
mywindow.moveTo(0, 0);
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="solopopup()"><li>one</li></a> <!--This goes to url above -->
<a href="#" onclick="solopopup()"><li>Two</li></a> <!--This goes to a different url -->
```

is there a way to make the url change depending on what link I click so I don't have to rewrite the function for every link?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Pass the url as a parameter to the function.

Comment: That is a very obtuse argument and the fact that your argument is you "how you presented your question" makes me want to know the original question before you deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass the url as a parameter to the function

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function solopopup(url)
        {
        mywindow = window.open(url,"mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=768,height=850");
        mywindow.moveTo(0, 0);
        }

        <a href="#" onclick="solopopup('http://www.sample.com/solopopup')"><li>one</li></a> <!--This goes to url above -->
        <a href="#" onclick="solopopup('http://www.sample.com/solopopup')"><li>Two</li></a> <!--This goes to a different url -->
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say what you changed, and why. Also, mind those quotes. Clicking either link above will give you a JavaScript error.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to pass the url to the function as an argument.

**html**

```
<a href="#" onclick="solopopup('http://www.mysite1.com')"><li>one</li></a>
<a href="#" onclick="solopopup('http://www.mysite2.com')"><li>Two</li></a>
```

**javascript**

```
function solopopup(url)
{
    mywindow = window.open(url,"mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=768,height=850");
    mywindow.moveTo(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the JS out of the anchors and use data attributes to store the URLs.

HTML

```
<a class="url" data-url="http://one.com">
  <li>one</li>
</a>

<a class="url" data-url="http://two.com">
  <li>Two</li>
</a>
```

JS

```
function solopopup(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  mywindow = window.open(this.dataset.url, "mywindow", "menubar=1,resizable=1,width=768,height=850");
  mywindow.moveTo(0, 0);
}

var urls = document.querySelectorAll('.url');

[].slice.call(urls).forEach(function (a) {
  a.addEventListener('click', solopopup, false);
});
```

Comment: up voted because this answer, unlike the others, includes an event.preventDefault().

Answer (score 0):

Your links ares obtrusive because they won't work if JS is disabled. Better use

```js
function mylinkHandler() {
  var mywindow = window.open(this.href, "mywindow", "menubar=1,resizable=1,width=768,height=850");
  mywindow.moveTo(0, 0);
}
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mylink'), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', mylinkHandler);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="mylink" href="http://www.example.com/one">one</a></li>
  <li><a class="mylink" href="http://www.example.com/two">two</a></li>
</ul>
```